# After diabling the local video track remote users are still able to see local stream

Tags: reactjs, video-streaming, agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

This is the logic that i have written to mute the video and audio

```
  const mute = async(type)=>{
      if(type==="audio"){
        await tracks[0].setEnabled(!trackState.audio);
        setTrackState((ps)=>{
          return {...ps, audio:!ps.audio};
        });
      }
      else if(type==="video"){
        await tracks[1].setEnabled(!trackState.video);
        console.log("iamclosign my video", tracks[1], client.uid)
        setTrackState((ps)=>{
          return {...ps, video:!ps.video};
        });
      }
  }
```

and below is where i am calling this function

```
<button className='btn' onClick={()=>mute("audio")}>
      {trackState.audio?<i class="fa-solid fa-microphone fa-2xl mx-2" style={{'color': '#ffffff'}}></i>
      :<i class="fa-solid fa-microphone-slash fa-2xl mx-2" style={{'color': '#ffffff'}}></i>}
      </button>
      <button className='btn' onClick={()=>mute("video")}>
          {trackState.video?<i class="fa-solid fa-video fa-2xl mx-2" style={{'color': '#ffffff'}}></i>
          :<i class="fa-solid fa-video-slash fa-2xl mx-2" style={{'color': '#ffffff'}}></i>}
      </button>
```

after pressing the video mute button only for local user the stream is disbabled but the other users (remote) are able to see the video
local users console
[image: console of local user]
remote user console
[image: console of remoter side]

I am trying to write a code for audio vedio on off button
but the vedio is not disabling from remote side although it is disabled from user side